# Express session cookies not set. Backend deployed on Render and frontend deployed using Vercel. Works on localhost though

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past 2 days, and I have yet to find the solution.

My application is divided into client and server. Client is hosted on vercel and server hosted on Render. I am using jwt tokens for login authentication. This works on localhost but not when both the front and backend are deployed.

Server index.js

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://frontend.vercel.app'],
  methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT'],
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(
  session({
    key: 'id',
    secret:  process.env.JWTKEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    name: 'session',
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    }
  })
);
```

Client login functions

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()  
    axios.post('https://render.com/api/login', values, { withCredentials: true })
    .then(res => {
      if(res.data) {
        console.log(res.data);
        console.log("Login Successful");
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        alert(res.data.Error);
      }
    })
    .then(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

I hope someone can help me this! Thank you very much :)

I have tried almost anything I found on the internet, including secure, sameSite, maxAge, proxy